# stack using linked list

Tags: c++, g++

I got "segmentation error" in my code. what is wrong? thanks in advance. p.s it's a stack using linked list.

```
#include <iostream>
//stack using linked list
class LinkedList {
 public:
  LinkedList() : head(0), tail(0) {}
  ~LinkedList() {
    while (!empty()) pop();
    delete head;
  }
  void pop() {
    node* temp;
    temp = head;
    for ( ; temp->next_ != tail; temp = temp->next_) {
      tail = temp;   
    }
    delete temp;
    tail->next_ = 0;
  } //removes, but does not return, the top element
  int top() {
    return tail->value_;
  } //returns, but does not remove, the top element
  bool empty() {
    return head == 0;
  }
  void push(const int& value) {
    node* element = new node(value);
    if (empty()) {
      head = tail = element;
    } else {
      tail->next_ = element;
      tail = element;
    }
  } //place a new top element
 private:
  class node {
   public:
    node(const int& input) : value_(input), next_(0) {};
    int value_; //store value
    node* next_; //link to the next element
  };
  node* head;
  node* tail;
};
int main() {
  LinkedList list;
  list.push(1);
  list.push(2);
  list.push(3);
  list.pop();
  std::cout << list.top() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code with `gdb` ?

Comment: Did it occur to you that you should atleast tell where your code crashed?

Answer (score 2):

This part doesn't look right

```
for ( ; temp->next_ != tail; temp = temp->next_) {
    tail = temp;
}
```

because once you set `tail` to be the same as `temp`, `temp->next != tail` will always be true.

Comment: it does give me the correct answer. but it says "double free or corruption"

Answer (score 1):

```
for ( ; temp->next_ != tail; temp = temp->next_) {
      tail = temp;   
}
```

The condition should have been

```
temp->next_ != 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This method

```
  void pop() {
    node* temp;
    temp = head;
    for ( ; temp->next_ != tail; temp = temp->next_) {
      tail = temp;   
    }
    delete temp;
    tail->next_ = 0;
  } //removes, but does not return, the top element
```

must be like this:

```
  void pop() {
    if( head == tail )
    {
        delete head;
        head = 0;
    } 
    else
    {
        node* temp;
        temp = head;
        for ( ; temp->next_ != tail; temp = temp->next_) {
        }
        delete tail;
        temp->next_ = 0;
        tail = temp;
    }
  } //removes, but does not return, the top element
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think is:

```
for ( ; temp->next_ != tail; temp = temp->next_) {
  tail = temp;   
}
delete temp;
tail->next_ = 0;
```

tail = temp should be after you find the temp that leads to tail (i.e. outside of the for loop).
Also, temp = not the tail but the one before the tail. So probably you need:

```
for ( ; temp->next_ != tail; temp = temp->next_) {}
delete tail;
tail = temp;
tail->next_ = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The destructor looks buggy to me: you keep "popping" until empty() returns true, which happens when head is the null pointer. But then you can't call delete on head after the while loop is over...

I don't know if this is the issue, but I would check it.

Another humble tip: you didn't tell us where the seg fault happens... If you run your code with gdb (or if you just put a lot of "cout" in your code), you can detect the line that causes you problems.